# PostgreSQL IN query performance on a larger array

Tags: postgresql, optimization, postgresql-performance

I'm fairly new to PostgreSQL and have a question about query performance.

I get a set of values by parsing a file and want to count how many of them already exist in a specific column in my database (PostgreSQL). Currently I do this by parsing the whole file, storing its values in an array and then executing an IN query as follows:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(id)) FROM "account"
WHERE name IN ('name1', 'name2', 'name3');
```

The column "name" which is being queried has a unique index on it.

I am wondering if this approach would be optimal if the array grows larger (20.000+ values) and/or I execute the query on a table with 40.000+ existing rows. Or is there a better approach?

Comment: please read https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3034/asking-query-performance-questions/3035#3035 and edir your question

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but: `distinct` is not a function. Putting the column name that follows between parentheses achieves nothing.

Comment: Sometimes rewriting an `IN` to a JOIN against a values clause makes things faster. Something along the lines of this: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=0c33129ed4be961b98263689a081a99b

Comment: To be clear, you are passing a *list of values* in your example, not an *array*. That's a relevant difference. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31192557/939860

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Correctness

First things first.

> I [...] want to count how many of the words already exist in a specific column

Your query does not do that if there can be **duplicates** in the input, and the misplaced `DISTINCT` keyword in the query suggests as much.

When passing `('name1', 'name1', 'name1')`, with 'name1' in the table, the correct answer is: ***3***. But your query says ***1***.

The `DISTINCT` keyword makes sure of it, but it's a complete waste. The [`IN` construct](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparisons.html#FUNCTIONS-COMPARISONS-IN-SCALAR) folds duplicates in the input implicitly, and there are no duplicates in your *unique* column. `IN` is the **wrong tool** to answer your question to begin with. One of these queries would do that:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM   unnest(ARRAY['name1', 'name1', 'name1']) name
JOIN   account USING (name);

SELECT count(*)
FROM   unnest(ARRAY['name1', 'name1', 'name1']) i(name)
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT FROM account a WHERE a.name = i.name);
```

The first one counts duplicates in the table (*multiplied* with duplicates on the same name in the input), the second one does not. Since there are no duplicates in the table, both do the same.

#### Adapted question

Let's assume you meant to ask:

***How many of the words in my table are listed in the input (at least once)?***

Now duplicates in the input don't matter (logically), and `IN` fits the job description. But we still don't need `DISTINCT` while the table column is unique (and rows are not multiplied by joins or similar).

Removing `DISTINCT` makes it faster already. Next, there is no need to involve the additional column `id`. Insignificant as though this may seem, it can force an ***index scan*** instead of an ***[index only scan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-index-only-scans.html)***. `count(name)` is typically faster (and safer). But use `count(*)` instead. Faster, yet. And equivalent while `id` is the PK:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM account WHERE name IN ('name1', 'name2', 'name3');
```

With modern Postgres that should be about the optimum for your case. You should see index-only scans on the unique index (if the table is vacuumed enough, [read the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-index-only-scans.html)), which is as fast as it gets, even with thousands of search terms. In particular do ***not*** rewrite with `UNION` or `OR` as has been suggested. That would get you a much more verbose and slower query.

Nor will it be faster to put the words in a (temporary) table first. That might be useful if you go on to do more with it, but not for this query alone.

Comment: Thank you, your answer was very helpful.